# Puzzling "reference to println is ambiguous" compilation error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, overloading, conditional-operator, ambiguous

If I compile and run the following class (with Java SE 7, if that matters),

```
class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(true ? null : 42);
        // System.out.println(null);
    }
}
```

I get the following output

```
null
```

So far, so good. However, if I uncomment the second statement in `main`, I get a compilation error:

```
Foo.java:5: error: reference to println is ambiguous, both method println(char[]) in PrintStream and method println(String) in PrintStream match

      System.out.println(null);
                  ^
```

Why does the Java compiler throw this error if the argument of 
`System.out.println` is `null`, but doesn't if the argument is `true ? null : 42`?

Comment: Java 8 probably handles the autoboxing between null and an int?

Comment: java 8 [linux] the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of the expression `true ? null : 42` is `Integer` therefore it is unambiguous that `System.println(Object)` should be called.

If you call `System.println(null)` there are multiple candidate methods and the compiler can't decide which one to take.

Comment: The type is `Integer` to be exact...